# How to use a module in typescript (array syntax)?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

```js
import http from "http";
import https from "https";

const module = (options.port === 443 ? "https" : "http");

const req = [module].request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

error TS2339: Property 'request' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[module]` array syntax should be changed to `module`.

Additionally, you should use conditional importing to only import the module that you require. Please note that because `import` returns a promise, you will need to add the code in your example into an `async` function and prepend `await` in front of each `import` statement:

```
async function invokeHttpRequest() {
  const module = (options.port === 443 ? await import("https") : await import("http"));

  const req = module.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import http from "HTTP";
import https from "https";

const module = (options.port === 443 ? https : http);

const req = module.request(options, (res) => {
   console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```